# How to make textview as card view in android using background resource

Tags: android, textview

This is Textview :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_naer_me"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
    android:text=“Hello”
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_border"
    />
```

This background resource

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/light_gray" />
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />


</shape>
```

current view is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrz9D.png)

expected view is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niC1P.png)

please suggest me how to achieve this i want make textview as card view you can see my given screen

Comment: just put your textview inside cardview

Comment: android:elevation="40dp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are lots of ways and here they are Use that which one suits you**

> Create your own drawable

**border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and **your_layout.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:background="@drawable/border"
  />
```

> You can also use use a drawable from android

```
android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"
```

or:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
```

or:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

> Use a 9-patch image with a shadow and set it as the background to your
>   Linear layout

Use this website to create 9 patch with shadow

http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

Answer (score 0):

> Use **android:elevation="20dp"** and **background**  same effect
>   like 
>        cardview without wrap cardview

```
        <TextView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
         />
```